# Convert date and time from output

Tags: time, sed, awk, date

I have a file with date and time on a couple thousand lines.

I need to convert:

```
2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000
```

To:

```
02/Aug/2019-01:23:50 +0000
```

I so far have

```
th=`grep -o '\[.*\]' test.txt | sed 's/\"//g' | head -1
echo $th | date -d +'%Y/%b/%d-%T'

date: invalid date ‘+%Y/%b/%d-%T’
```

How can I read in the date and format it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
echo '2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000' | awk -F'/|\+|-' -v month=$(echo '2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000' | awk -F'-' '{print $1}'|date +%b -f -) '{printf "%s/%s/%s-%s +%s\n", $3,month,$1,$4,$5}'
```

In one line or

```
MONTH=$(echo '2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000' | awk -F'-' '{print $1}'|date +%b -f -)
echo '2019/08/02-01:23:50+0000' | awk -F'/|\+|-' -v month="$MONTH" '{printf "%s/%s/%s-%s +%s\n", $3,month,$1,$4,$5}'
```

First step is to extract 2019/08/02 and convert 08 to Aug then with multiple separators extract all fields and `printf` with the format we want. Tricky thing here, passing `shell` variable to `awk` (fill free to remove `\n` in `printf` format)